# Why can I send the same message to different receivers?

Tags: ruby

If I write a method like this:

```
def print_message(text, string)
   text.print_line string
end
```

Ruby will send a message called #print_line to different methods in the rest of my code. These methods will all implement #print_line in different ways. For instance:

```
class PutsText
  def print_line(string)
    puts(string + "\n")
  end
end

class UpcaseText
  def print_line(string)
    puts(string.upcase + "\n")
  end
end

print_message PutsText.new, "Text"
print_message UpcaseText.new, "uppercase text"
```

I believe that this is what is called polymorphism.

Now, what I don't understand is that this code also works:

```
def print_message(text, string)
   text.print_line string
end

def print_number(number, float)
   number.print_line float
end

class PutsText
   def print_line(string)
     puts(string + "\n")
   end
end

class UpcaseText
  def print_line(string)
    puts(string.upcase + "\n")
  end
end

class PutsNumber
  def print_line(float)
    puts(float)
  end
end

print_message PutsText.new, "Text"
print_message UpcaseText.new, "uppercase text"
print_number PutsNumber.new, (3.56 + 1.27)
```

Shouldn't the message #print_line be ambiguous for Ruby in different contexts like this?

Comment: This is actually called "duck typing" and is a large part of ruby's nature Nice minimalistic explanation http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/duck_typing.html

Comment: I cannot see any ambiguity in the posted code. You can even write `print_message PutsNumber.new, (3.56 + 1.27)` and you'll get the same result as with `print_number`. Still nothing ambiguous.

Comment: @axiac I need to think more about how the messages are passed in Ruby. Thank you!

Comment: @engineersmnky Nice explanation in the link.